# Color of active input placeholder text CSS3

Tags: forms, css

How do i set the **placeholder color** of the active input, but that doesn't work.. I tried following:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder:active {
color:    blue;
}
:-moz-placeholder:active {
color:    blue;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder:active {
color:    blue;
}
```

What i am after is same effect as the inputs on https://twitter.com/ ..

Solution so far:

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:    blue;
}
:focus:-moz-placeholder {
color:    blue;
}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
color:    blue;
}
```

​

Comment: Active is the wrong word here - the correct term is focus. Even so, `::-webkit-input-placeholder:focus` won't work because you can't have a pseudo-class after a pseudo-element. But try and see if `:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder` works for WebKit.

Comment: Ah i see.. so i got to do this with jQuery i guess... just seem a little wierd that the active or focus color cant be set with css..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `:active` pseudo class, instead use `:focus`

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VckY5/1/)

`:active` styles only applies when you keep an element `clicked`, so use `:focus` for input fields...

CSS

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: blue;
}
:-moz-placeholder:focus {
   color: blue;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder:focus {
   color: blue;
}
```

Preview

[image]

Comment: Okay i see. but the :focus doesn't seem to change the color though

Comment: @Saggo does change for me, which browser are you using

Comment: I got it working by setting :focus in front like BoltClock said.. I am using Chrome .. If i set :focus last then the text is still grey at focus

Comment: As I mentioned above, you need to switch the selectors around for WebKit because you can't have a `:pseudo-class` after a `::pseudo-element`.

Comment: BoltClock's right, using [`:focus` first seemed to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2cw/).

Comment: Sorry how can I miss that, @BoltClock is right, you can't declare `pseudo-class` after `pseudo-element`

Comment: That makes sense.. Thanks for the help both! @BoltClock you didn't make an answer i can accept ? :)

Comment: @Saggo: I wasn't sure as I'm not familiar with placeholder pseudos, but now that you have an answer, I have no reason to post another :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this you looking for? I am not sure...

[My Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/BbZZb/12/)

```
input {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 100px;

    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    font-size: 14px;

    transition:.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition:.2s linear;
    -moz-transition:.2s linear;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #61C5FA;
    border-color: #61C5FA;
}

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:    blue;
}
```

Change the placeholder text bluecolor into whatever you like... If, its not just explain more...

Thanks